# How to save pipe through bunyan CLI tool logs to log file instead of json format

Tags: node.js, bunyan

How I can save logs generated by bunyan CLI tool by using command to run server node . | bunyan 
to server.log instead of json format in server.log file.

On console logs:-
[2018-05-14T12:28:01.465Z]  INFO: sampleApplication/12840: hi

server.log:-
{"name":"sampleApplication","pid":12840,"level":30,"msg":"hi","time":"2018-05-14T12:28:01.465Z","v":0}

How can both be same in console and server.log?

Answer (score 0):

You can try add different streams in your bunyan init config:

```
bunyan.createLogger({
    name: 'name',
    streams: [{
      path: './logs/file.log'
    }, {
        level : 'debug',
        stream : process.stdout
    }]
  });
```